# How to cross compile pyinstaller bootloader to arm 32bit

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller

How to cross compile pyinstaller-3.5 boot loader for arm soft float 32bit.

I tried to cross compile it:

getting error dl  not found.

```
python2.7 ./waf CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc all
'all' finished successfully (0.000s)
'distclean' finished successfully (0.000s)
Setting top to                           : /home/arjuncr/Downloads/PyInstaller-3.5/bootloader 
Setting out to                           : /home/arjuncr/Downloads/PyInstaller-3.5/bootloader/build 
Python Version                           : 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) [GCC 7.4.0] 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
Checking size of pointer                 : 4 
Platform                                 : Linux-32bit detected based on compiler 
Checking for flags -m32                  : yes 
Checking for program 'arm-linux-gnueabi-strip' : /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-strip 
Checking for program 'strip'                   : /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-strip 
Checking for library dl                        : not found 
The configuration failed
(complete log in /home/arjuncr/Downloads/PyInstaller-3.5/bootloader/build/config.log)
```

log:

```
[1/2] Compiling build/.conf_check_c80cac29ed913c100609f182ebb9efef/test.c

['arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc', '-m32', '-O2', '-Wdeclaration-after-statement', '-Wimplicit-function-declaration', '-Werror', '-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE', '-D_REENTRANT', '-D_BSD_SOURCE', '-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE', '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2', '../test.c', '-c', '-o/home/arjuncr/Downloads/PyInstaller-3.5/bootloader/build/.conf_check_c80cac29ed913c100609f182ebb9efef/testbuild/test.c.1.o']
err: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m32’

from /home/arjuncr/Downloads/PyInstaller-3.5/bootloader: Test does not build: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arjuncr/Downloads/PyInstaller-3.5/bootloader/.waf-2.0.9-6b5f17f340ec613b295ffa3dedcecc80/waflib/Configure.py", line 324, in run_build
    bld.compile()
  File "/home/arjuncr/Downloads/PyInstaller-3.5/bootloader/.waf-2.0.9-6b5f17f340ec613b295ffa3dedcecc80/waflib/Build.py", line 176, in compile
    raise Errors.BuildError(self.producer.error)
BuildError: Build failed
 -> task in 'testprog' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)

not found
from /home/arjuncr/Downloads/PyInstaller-3.5/bootloader: The configuration failed
```

Also I used crosss compiled version of python 2.7.17

```
./configure --enable-shared     \
            --with-system-expat \
            --with-ensurepip=yes \
            --enable-unicode=ucs4 \
            --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu\
            --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu \
             --enable-ipv6            \
             ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=no  \
             ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no    &&
make
```

Used cross compiled version of zlib

`CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc ./configure && make`
and copied the lib to `/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/`

```
Editing the wsscript  
<pre>   
--- wscript 2019-07-10 00:44:04.000000000 +0530
+++ ../../../PyInstaller-3.5/bootloader/wscript 2020-01-04 23:05:17.877519450 +0530
@@ -366,9 +366,9 @@
                 # on 32-bit arm Linux. So skip the -m32 flag.
                 pass
             else:
-                ctx.check_cc(ccflags='-m32', msg='Checking for flags -m32')
-                ctx.env.append_value('CFLAGS', '-m32')
-                ctx.env.append_value('LINKFLAGS', '-m32')
+                ctx.check_cc(ccflags='', msg='Checking for flags -m32')
+                ctx.env.append_value('CFLAGS', '')
+                ctx.env.append_value('LINKFLAGS', '')
             # Set LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE_FLAG to True.
             # On Windows this allows 32bit apps to use 4GB of memory and
             # not only 2GB.
</pre>
```

Comment: how tio sove this error `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m32' `

Comment: You'll have to either tweak the setup script (pass some option to it or patch the source) so that it doesn't use this option at all, or create, say, a Python script called `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` instead of the actual compiler executable and have it remove this argument and pass the rest to the compiler

Comment: I tried to remove the m32 flag from script. now able to build the pyinstaller bootloader.  (python2.7 ./waf CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --libdir=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/ all)

Comment: Able to see  ```file PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-32bit/run
PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-32bit/run: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=9fc87884fff1a9ef70c307fd4454279df6a915ea, stripped```

Comment: We have to change pyinstaller-3.5/PyInstaller/building/api.py +610 objcopy to arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy.